# how to chain Dependant Observables accordingly

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Relatively new to RxJava. Have below requirement. Any pointers would be helpful.
For ex:- Have 3 observables A,B,C such that

1. A emits data from data source like DB
2. B & C both depends on data from A.
3. B & C should execute in parallel
4. Observable D requires B & C to zip and produce combined result.

Tried something like below but it doesn't address #4 above where Observables B & C are required as such to for D to zip ( B,C).

```
Observable<A>.just("AdataSource")
  .flatMap(Asdata->{ callB(Asdata) },(Asdata,BsResult)->{callC(AsData)};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the interior form of the `publish()` operator.

```
Observable<A> dataSource;
Observable<Pair<B, C>> dObservable = dataSource
  .publish( ds ->
    Observable.zip( callB( ds ), callC( ds ), (b, c) -> new Pair<>(b, c)));
```

where the `callB()` and `callC()` methods have these signatures:

```
Observable<B> callB( Observable<A> dataSource );
Observable<C> callC( Observable<A> dataSource );
```

What the `publish()` operator does is bind the observable to `ds`, which can then be shared by the `B` and `C` observer chains.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Dalgleish . This helps! Also would like to know if usage of Pair could be avoided by any means so that the Observable<B>,Observable<C> could be received as such.

Comment: You can't "receive" the pair of observables. I used `Pair` as a common way to `zip()` together the values from the two observables. You can use whatever function you want to combine the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatMap your **ObservableA** with a zip of **ObservableB** and **ObservableC**.

Assume this is your ObservableA, ObservableB and ObservableC.

(Example code in Kotlin)

```
fun getObservableA(): Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
}

fun getObservableB(num: Int): Observable<String> {
    return Observable.just("${num}A", "${num}B")
}

fun getObservableC(num: Int): Observable<String> {
    return Observable.just("${num}a", "${num}b", "${num}c")
}
```

You start from calling `getObservableA()` and flatMap its results to a zip of `getObservableB(num)` and `getObservableC(num)`.

```
getObservableA()
        .flatMap { num ->
            Observable.zip(
                    getObservableB(num),
                    getObservableC(num),
                    BiFunction { t1: String, t2: String -> t1 to t2 }
            )
        }
        .subscribe(
                { (t1, t2) ->
                    // This will emit 6 times as follows:-
                    //   t1 = 1A, t2 = 1a
                    //   t1 = 1B, t2 = tb
                    //   t1 = 2A, t2 = 2a
                    //   t1 = 2B, t2 = 2b
                    //   t1 = 3A, t2 = 3a
                    //   t1 = 3B, t2 = 3b
                }
        )
```